# Fastest way to grind reputation for Horde Expedition

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In a post-Cata world, what's the fastest way to grind faction for Horde Expedition? I recently leveled my engineering on an alt and want to purchase the schematic for a Mechano-Hog. This requires exalted with Horde Expedition. Is there currently a way to get this all done in one day on a level 85? Does it really take weeks of grinding on daily quests?

Comment: sadly, yes it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Horde Expedition](http://www.wowwiki.com/Horde_Expedition) is made up of the combined forces of the horde in Northrend, these factions are:

- [The Hand of Vengeance](http://www.wowwiki.com/The_Hand_of_Vengeance),
- [The Taunka](http://www.wowwiki.com/The_Taunka),
- [Warsong Offensive](http://www.wowwiki.com/The_Warsong_Offensive),
- [The Sunreavers](http://www.wowwiki.com/The_Sunreavers)

Half of the reputation gains from the Horde Expedition's four factions count towards this the Horde Expedition's reputation. Therefore, you must have two of the four factions at Exalted in order to be exalted with the Horde Expedition, or the equivalent amount of reputation spread across all four.

You can farm reputation upto "Revered" simply by questing in Northrend. In addition to questing, you can do a handful of daily quests that will raise your reputation with the Horde Expedition. These are:

**Icecrown**

- [Blood of the Chosen](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=13330) - 125 reputation,
- [Assault by Air](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=13310) - 125 reputation,
- [Assault by Ground](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=13301) - 125 reputation,
- [King of the Mountain](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=13283) - 125 reputation,
- [Keeping the Alliance Blind](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=13331) - 125 reputation

In addition, the Argent Tournament Dailies should give reputation to these factions.

**Grizzly Hills (PvP Daily)**

- [Blackriver Brawl](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=12170) - 250 reputation,
- [Making the Repairs](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=12280) - 125 reputation,
- [Shred the Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=12270) - 125 reputation,
- [Keep 'Em on Their Heels](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=12284) - 125 reputation,
- [Overwhelmed](http://www.wowhead.com/?quest=12288) - 125 reputation

All [Wrath of the Lich King heroics](http://www.wowwiki.com/Instances_by_level#Wrath_of_the_Lich_King) will give reputation with all the Horde Expedition forces **without** a tabard equipped. In addition, the high end [Wrath of the Lich King normal instances](http://www.wowwiki.com/Instances_by_level#Wrath_of_the_Lich_King) will also give reputation with all of these factions. These instances are;

- [Utgarde Pinnacle](http://www.wowwiki.com/Utgarde_Pinnacle),
- [The Culling of Stratholme](http://www.wowwiki.com/Caverns_of_Time:_Culling_of_Stratholme),
- [The Oculus](http://www.wowwiki.com/Oculus),
- [Halls of Lightning](http://www.wowwiki.com/Halls_of_Lightning)

As a level 85 damage dealing class, solo'ing Wrath of the Lich King instances should not present itself as a problem, clearing all of them will go some distance to farming the reptuation you need to get to exhalted with this faction.

Comment: Pixel pretty much sumed up all the dailies you can do. I've personally grinded from 0 to exalted in the alliance counterpart Alliance Vanguard by doing my dailies and running Heroic Utgarde pinnacle and Heroic Utgarde Keep. Roughly took me a week of doing this.

Comment: Running WotLK heroics could be tough for an average-geared 85, but I guess that varies with individual, class and skills.

Comment: Yeah no doubt, I did it on my hunter which makes things easier I guess.